# Volumes and surfaces of revolution?

Tags: calculus, surfaces

Please can someone explain to me why we use $dx$ in a volume of revolution i.e. $$\pi \int{f(x)^2 dx}$$ but $ds$ (an elementary bit of arc) in a surface of revolution i.e. $$2\pi \int{f(x)ds}$$ does this not mean you are under or over estimating the volume in the volume of revolution

Comment: I think you mean $\int f(s)ds$ in the 2nd integral. The "$x$" and "$s$" appearing in the integral are mute variables, you can use "pretty anything you want", as long as notation is consistent and does not conflict with earlier  (or commonly used) notations (e.g. $\int f(@)d@$...). However $dx$ "normally" means integral with respect to Lebesgue measure (dimension given by context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as $dx \to 0$ the over/under-estimation of volume you note dwindles to zero. however this does not apply to the computation of surface area. you can see the same principle more clearly if you compare the usual procedure for computing the area under a curve with the requirements of computing an arc length for the same function.